# How do I resize a fixed footer background image to my desired resolution?

Tags: css, background, resize, footer, resolution

Please what do I have to add or change here to reduce the footer-bg to a pixel with width: 100; and height: 18;?
I'll be glad if this is looked on now as I need this help now.
Gracias.

```
#footer-bg {
  background:#1f512e;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  min-height: 43px;
}

.footer-top {
  height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: so set width: 100px; height: 18px;  like that?

Comment: Trust me. This suggestion doesn't work. I've tried it, instead it shifts the footer-bg to the left. Here's the link to the site i'm currently working on, inspect the footer and respond back thanks donald.soutechventures.com

Comment: Do you want the green bar to take up 100% at the bottom or just 100px at the bottom?

Comment: or do you want the green bar to take up 960px like the rest of your content?

Comment: Is you observe closely, you'll notice that the Logo at the top-left and the Search bar and "Call us" (at the top right) have this invincible dimension.

Also please take a look at the "Like Us on Facebook" widget (down right) also with the news and events(down left).

They both have this limit they stop (same as the top logo and the top search bar and "Call Us")

I want same margin constrain for the green footer-bg that is wide (covering the whole page)

Comment: If you observe i meant*****

Comment: yeah the 960px like the rest of my content

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your dimensions using

```
        width: 100px;
        height: 18px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9p6xbrn/2/

```
   #footer-bg {
        background:#1f512e;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 18px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        min-height: 43px;
    }
    .footer-top {
        height: 12px;
    }
```

Comment: Trust me. This suggestion doesn't work. I've tried it, instead it shifts the footer-bg to the left.
Here's the link to the site i'm currently working on, inspect the footer and respond back thanks 
http://donald.soutechventures.com/

Comment: @WiseManSoul-Tech  Hi, my solutions set the width to 100px and height  to 18px for #footer-bg... I believe it is what are you asking in your question.... Please articulate your question, maybe add an image of your final layout I would be glad to help you further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough.  If you want the green bar to be centered and take up 960px, do this.  My changes are at the bottom.

```
#footer-bg {
  background:#1f512e;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  min-height: 43px;

  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want to set your footer to 100% and have it match the rest of your content, you would have to create some sort of container to put all your content including the footer in.  Then set that container to a width of 960px with margin: 0 auto.